# Linked server select Openquery causing datetime column to be an hour behind?

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, ingres

I have a SQL 2014 server which has a linked server to an Actian Ingres database.

When I run a simple linked server select openquery on any table with date/times, the results it pulls back is an hour out compared to when I query the ingres database itself..

When I run the same openquery on an old SQL 2008 R2 instance it pulls back the correct time (the same time as the ingres database)

Query format:

```
SELECT * FROM 
OPENQUERY(linkedserver, 'select date/time column from tablename')
```

The server date/time zones are all the same, the odbc connection settings are all the same, the linked server settings and SQL instance settings are the same.

I have checked for any similar issues online but cannot find anything

Am I missing something here?

Comment: One hour adrift suggests daylight-saving-time is being applied differently.  Daylight saving comes out wrong whatever you do.  I think there is an option to disable daylight saving on Windows Server.  Spoiler: that won't fix your thing.  Oh, it might.  Until September, or is it October?

Comment: same time zone & daylight saving settings which is the weird thing

Comment: What driver names and versions are being used by both the 2008 R2 instance and the 2014 instance linked servers?